# Slack API Slash Command sent to ASP.NET Core MVC Web App Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, slack-api, slack-commands

I am having an issue with my web api in ASP.NET Core MVC receiving the POST request from the Slack API when I attempt to [execute a slash command](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands). I do have the app hosted on a dedicated server (with a valid SSL Cert) and it is reachable by the Slack API.

Here is the method I am using to receive the POST request from the Slack API:

```
    [HttpPost("slash/dispatch")]
    [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> ReceiveSlashDispatchEvent([FromForm] string data)
    {
        try
        {
            
            // string data;
            // using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            // {
            //     data = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            // }
            
            await _slackDispatchBotService.PostMessage(new SlackChatSendRequest
            {
                Channel = "XXXXXXX",
                Message = data
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok($"Error: {e.Message}");
        }
        
        return Ok();
    }
```

Now if I don't declare anything in the method signature, it actually does enter it correctly. I have been successful in retrieving the request body using that commented section and directly reading in the Stream.

Here is a class definition that I have used in the method body previously (and it would fail each time):

```
public class SlackSlashDispatchEvent
{
    public string Token { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("team_id")]
    public string TeamId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("team_domain")]
    public string TeamDomain { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("enterprise_id")]
    public string EnterpriseId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("enterprise_name")]
    public string EnterpriseName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("channel_id")]
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("channel_name")]
    public string ChannelName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("user_id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("user_name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Command { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("response_url")]
    public string ResponseUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("trigger_id")]
    public string TriggerId { get; set; }
}
```

I have also accessed the `Request.QueryString` field, which is always empty. Does anyone have a suggestion of where I should investigate further?

So far it seems to be that the framework I'm using is failing to successfully transform the request body data to whatever type I define in the method signature. Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time determining what the next troubleshooting steps are.

**EDIT**
While I have a strong feeling that there is a more graceful way to do this, I have implemented a solution. I do use the stream reader to grab the request body.

```
    string data;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        data = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
```

I then wrote this method to parse the URLEncoded query parameters (that for some reason get sent in the request body from the Slack API) to convert it to my desired class:

```
    public static SlackSlashDispatchEvent ParseQueryString(string queryString)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var items = queryString.Split('&');
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var keyValue = item.Split('=');
            var key = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(keyValue[0]);
            var value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(keyValue[1]);
            
            dict.Add(key, value);
        }

        var stringifyDict = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SlackSlashDispatchEvent>(stringifyDict)!;
    }
```

Serializing and then deserializing the Dictionary feels inefficient, but it's the best I could come up with for now.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm going to copy/paste this from my edit on the original post. I'll call this the answer.

EDIT While I have a strong feeling that there is a more graceful way to do this, I have implemented a solution. I do use the stream reader to grab the request body.

```
string data;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
{
    data = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

I then wrote this method to parse the URLEncoded query parameters (that for some reason get sent in the request body from the Slack API) to convert it to my desired class:

```
public static SlackSlashDispatchEvent ParseQueryString(string queryString)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var items = queryString.Split('&');
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var keyValue = item.Split('=');
        var key = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(keyValue[0]);
        var value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(keyValue[1]);
        
        dict.Add(key, value);
    }

    var stringifyDict = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict);
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SlackSlashDispatchEvent>(stringifyDict)!;
}
```

Serializing and then deserializing the Dictionary feels inefficient, but it's the best I could come up with for now.